# How to remove unwanted clutter from all of the individual page titles on a website?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A forum I am using has the long name of the site first, then the page-name of the thread in the title. So, I only can see the first 2 characters of the thread name in browser tabs.

I used this ["Change Page Title" script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24034) but it only changes one page's title at a time. How can I delete the superlongwebsitename on the title bar for all pages?

I want to change it so when I enter to *any* page on the site it shows only the thread name (the aforementioned script requires an entry for each individual page).

For HTML like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="superlongsitename / threadname" />
<title>superlongsitename / threadname</title>
```

I want the script to seek and delete the "superlongsitename" in all pages for a given site.

I tried this:

```
newString = str.replace("Tarantula&nbsp;- Sekiz Bacakli Güzeller /", )
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Modify the `window.document.title`?

Comment: how can i get that to only delete the superlongsitename part on code?

Comment: You could use a `.replace()` call on it. http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace for reference

Comment: Sorry for my noobness, where did i go wrong below?
'
newString = str.replace("Tarantula&nbsp;- Sekiz Bacakli Güzeller /", )'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site uses unicode characters which sometimes require special handling in [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).  But, fortunately, the site conveniently puts all of the cruft before a slash character (`/`).

So, you can use a regex like `/^[^\/]+\/\s*/` to catch it.

Here's a **complete script** that fixes the title:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Tarantula, smarter, less cluttered title.
// @namespace   tarantula.gen
// @include     http://www.tarantula.gen.tr/forum/*
// @include     https://www.tarantula.gen.tr/forum/*
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Delete everything before the first slash (/).
var newTitle    = document.title.replace (/^[^\/]+\/\s*/, "");
document.title  = newTitle;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can i share this with giving you the credit? Also can i change the title?

Comment: You're welcome, and you can share it.  Don't worry about credit for this.  Yes, you can change the title, but what and how did you mean?

Comment: I'm just gonna translate the title. Thanks again! :)